# How can I get the URL in OpenReadCompletedEvent when I use webclient

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, webclient

How can I get the URL in OpenReadCompletedEvent when I use webclient.

```
 WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
 webClient.OpenReadAsync(url);       // in event method I want get this url       
 webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(CardInfoDown_Completed);   


 private void CardInfoDown_Completed(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {           
            using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(e.Result))
            {
                // I want get the url here,
                // How to do this?
                string strStream = reader.ReadToEnd();              
            }
        }          
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why not keep the url as global? And access it in the event?

Answer (score 4):

```
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.BaseAddress = "http://hhh.com";
    webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://hhh.com"));       // in event method I want get this url       
    webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(CardInfoDown_Completed);
```

And:

```
private void CardInfoDown_Completed(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(e.Result))
        {
            // I want get the url here,
            // How to do this?
            var client = sender as WebClient;
            if (client != null)
            {
                var url = client.BaseAddress; //returns hhh.com
            }
            string strStream = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get the baseaddress as null in the completed event.. can u guess as to why??

Answer (score 1):

Anton Sizikov's solution is good, but will only work if the URL is absolute (like `http://hhh.com`). If using a relative URL, .NET will automatically merge the base address with the relative URL (therefore potentially resulting in an invalid URL).

To send a value to the `OpenReadCompleted` event handler, you're supposed to use this `OpenRead` overload to provide a custom token (in this case, your URL): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144212(v=vs.95).aspx

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://hhh.com"), "http://hhh.com");
webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(CardInfoDown_Completed);
```

Then to retrieve the value:

```
private void CardInfoDown_Completed(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(e.Result))
        {
            var url = (string)e.UserState;
            string strStream = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me even a simpler variation from the above works fine

```
    private void CardInfoDown_Completed(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string url;

        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            url  = (string)e.UserState;
        }
       // ...
    }
```

Comment: Well, I used DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs  but in reality it probably has the same constituents as the previous examples..